# stop a pynput listener python

Tags: python, multithreading, pynput

I know there may be an answer already out there, but from what I've looked up for python, I really can't find a very straightforward answer on how to stop a pynput Listener.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
from threading import Thread

stopThreads = True

def on_press(key):
    if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
        print("pressed a")

def starting():
    global stopThreads
    while True:
        if stopThreads == True:
            with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
                if listener.is_alive():
                    pass    
                else:
                    listener.join()
        elif stopThreads == False:
            listener.stop()

t = Thread(target=starting)
t.start()

time.sleep(5)
print("stop")

stopThreads = False
```

Im not sure what this looks to you guys, but for this would look like it works perfectly but in reality it doesnt even register if i pressed "a" so im a bit confused on how the pynput listener can be stopped if a variable is False and how to keep it a thread in the background

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, Im just very blinded right now, because i didnt even need to use a listener, i could just say

```
stopThreads = True

def detectPress():
    global stopThreads
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if stopThreads == False:
            print("stopping")
            break
        else:
            if keyboard.is_pressed("a"):
                print("a")

t = Thread(target=detectPress)
t.start()


time.sleep(5)
stopThreads = False
```